# Invert product regular-price and old-price

Tags: price, products, discount, bundled-product, bundle

someone could help me to know how to invert regular-price and old-price on bundles products (M2).
I found other threads about but them seems to not run on my site.

So I need to have as first old-price (strikethrough text) and than Regular-price.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

not really.

I need just to have old-price (stiketrought) and than discounted price.

[image]